# Does the Twitter API auto shorten URLs

Tags: oauth, twitter

I know this question has been asked before however the answers I found where a little old and I know that [twitter has now made the t.co/xyz service manditory on all posts recently.](https://support.twitter.com/articles/109623-faqs-about-twitter-s-link-service-http-t-co/) I'm just wondering if when using the oAuth API service it will automatically shorten any url? Anyone know what the current process in play is? Do I still need to shorten the url pre posting?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Even when using OAuth, all links will be wrapped in t.co short URLs.  Even if the link is shorter than 20 characters!

[See the post in the discussion groups](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2806).

There is also some [documentation about recent and upcoming changes to t.co shortening](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper) (2012-04-12).

You can shorten the URL yourself if you want, but it will still get wrapped.